# How to write log insight query to get percentage of an alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

So I have log messages containing fields like:

```
numberOfPlayers: 50
team: Alice
```

```
numberOfPlayers: 60
team: Alice
```

```
numberOfPlayers: 70
team: Bob
```

```
numberOfPlayers: 40
team: Bob
```

I want to get 99th percentile across largest numberOfPlayers in a team, basically I want to get `p99(bob team's largest numberOfPlayers, alice team's largest numberOfPlayers, ....)`

I've written this log insight query to successfully get largest numberOfPlayers across all unique teams as an alias called `largeset`:

```
fields @log
| pct(numberOfPlayers, 100) as largest group by team
```

So results became:

```
largeset       team
60             Alice
70             Bob
```

But when I tried to get p99 percentile on the alias `largest` like this:

```
fields @log
| pct(numberOfPlayers, 100) as largest group by team 
| pct(largest, 99)
```

It won't let me to do so, syntax error.

Is it possible to do such `pct()` on an alias? If not, how should I write the query to get this single value of p99?